# Microsoft Graph API Request Body Not Working

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api

On the `developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer` I try to post a create page request in OneNote and the default code that gets populated in the request header looks like this:

```
KEY: Content-type       VALUE: multipart/form-data
     boundary                  MyPartBoundary198374
```

And the request body looks like this:

```
--MyPartBoundary198374
Content-Disposition:form-data; name="Presentation"
Content-Type:text/html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>A page with <i>rendered</i> images and an <b>attached</b> file</title>
    <meta name="created" content="2015-07-22T09:00:00-08:00" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Here's an image from an online source:</p>
    <img src="http://..." alt="an image on the page" width="500" />
    <p>Here's an image uploaded as binary data:</p>
    <img src="name:imageBlock1" alt="an image on the page" width="300" />
    <p>Here's a file attachment:</p>
    <object data-attachment="FileName.pdf" data="name:fileBlock1" type="application/pdf" />
  </body>
</html>

--MyPartBoundary198374
Content-Disposition:form-data; name="imageBlock1"
Content-Type:image/jpeg

... binary image data ...

--MyPartBoundary198374
Content-Disposition:form-data; name="fileBlock1"
Content-Type:application/pdf

... binary file data ...

--MyPartBoundary198374--
```

The response preview still gives me an error saying:

```
Page create requests require the content to be multipart, with a presentation part.
```

Considering the request headers and request body was generated by Microsoft shouldn't this Work? I have the correct section-id to write to the page, so I'm pretty confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that I was missing was that in the request header instead of having the value of `multipart/form-data` I changed it to `text/html`

Comment: I feel stupid for wasting 10 mins on this, but this is the correct answer. The graph explorer should be pre-populated with right content.

Comment: @Gvancha yeah it was a pain for me when I was first wrangling with the problem lol